# How to catch 422 Unprocessable entry in laravel 5.5.16

Tags: api, postman, laravel-5.5, http-status-code-422

How to catch 422 Unprocessable entry in laravel 5.5.16 ?

I am getting below error message while I am sending `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/topics` API request.

[image]

I would like to customize this error.In this regard I would like to know Which class and function producing this error and their location.

Comment: Try showing us the code that causes this issue... Without that, we have no clue what hitting that API endpoint does.

Answer (score 1):

A 422 Error is thrown when Laravel validates your Request data and the data is wrong, invalid or not processable.

---

If you are validating your data in an extra Request class, you can add a `message` method to override the error messages (further info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation)):

```
/**
 * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'body.required'  => 'A message is required',
    ];
}
```

---

If you are validating the data inside your Controller through `$request->validate(...)`, you need to create an own Validator class inline with a messages argument (further info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#working-with-error-messages)):

```
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Comment: Thanks @manniL for your reply. But I would like get a message like `{
    "data": {
        "message": "The body field is required."
    }
}` . What should I do ?